# Specifying jquery mobile data themes within a Rails 3.0 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I would like to specify a jquery mobile theme for an element in a rails 3.0 form. The following doesn't work.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">            

   ... #content formatted with data theme a

   <div data-role="checkbox" data-theme="c">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
   </div>

   ... #content formatted with data them a

</div>
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: shanabus solution in rails format -

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, { 'data-theme' => 'c' } %>
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work about it?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @shanabus, no error msg. The data theme for the page is a. I am trying to change the data-theme to c. It remains a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to specify the theme of a checkbox in jQuery Mobile, you would have to set it directly on the checkbox element. Could be something like this:

```
<%= f.check_box("label", "accepted", { 'data-theme' => 'c' }, "yes", "no") %>
```

Here is the docs for jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/checkboxes/options.html

And for a Rails example of adding attributes to a check_box: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

Hope this helps!

Comment: Check out the update, surrounded `data-theme` with single quotes.  That should work.  If not, please post error message in comments so I can help.